# PGP (GnuPG) - what was the original filename?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

John wants to send `1.txt` to Paul.

He encrypts it. Now the file is named `myFile.pgp`, and he sends it to Paul.

Paul gets the file.

How (if possible) can Paul know what the original file name (`1.txt`) was? Is there a parameter (`--xxx`) to see the filename ?

I'm using GNU PGP (GnuPG) in **console** mode.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With GnuPG, the original filename can be seen in **`gpg --list-packets`**.

```
$ gpg --list-packets test.gpg
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid CE7B5510340F19EF
    data: [4095 bits]
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 67
    mdc_method: 2
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID CE7B5510340F19EF, created 2009-10-31
      "Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>"
:compressed packet: algo=2
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1356362981, name="passwords.txt",
    raw data: 8 bytes
```

(Note: The entire literal data packet, including the filename, is *encrypted.* If you don't have the private key, you cannot see the name either.)

---

Alternatively, you can use `--decrypt` along with with **`--verbose`** (or `-v -d` for short):

```
$ gpg --verbose --decrypt test.gpg > NUL
gpg: public key is CE7B5510340F19EF
gpg: using subkey CE7B5510340F19EF instead of primary key D24F6CB2C1B52632
4096-bit RSA key, ID CE7B5510340F19EF, created 2009-10-31
         (subkey on main key ID D24F6CB2C1B52632)
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID CE7B5510340F19EF, created 2009-10-31
      "Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>"
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: original file name='passwords.txt'
```

(In Linux, use `> /dev/null` instead.)

---

If you want to **decrypt and save** the entire file, use the **`--use-embedded-filename`** option:

```
$ gpg -v --use-embedded-filename test.gpg
…boring output…
gpg: original file name='passwords.txt'
File `passwords.txt' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) n
```

(Note: You *should not* use `-d` or `--decrypt` with this option, since it never uses the embedded filename. Instead, use the "default" action.)

---

Do not forget that *not all* files have names. In Linux, `gpg` is often used to encrypt another program's output directly, without saving it in a file. It would then show up as:

```
$ echo Testing | gpg --store | gpg --list-packets
:compressed packet: algo=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1356362394, name="",
    raw data: 8 bytes
```

When *encrypting* (or just storing), the embedded filename can be changed with `--set-filename`.

```
$ echo Testing | gpg --store --set-filename "test.txt" | gpg --list-packets
:compressed packet: algo=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1356362790, name="test.txt",
    raw data: 8 bytes
```

Comment: the `--list-packets` doesn't extract. just display...(right ? )

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right. But it *does* decrypt, since some packets (including the original filename) are encrypted.

Comment: what is the `-v` . it doesnt appear in `gpg -?`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's the short form of `--verbose`. (Just like `-?` and `-d` are the short forms of `--help` and `--decrypt`.) My version of GnuPG *does* show it as: "-v, --verbose" under the "Options" section.

Comment: I dont understand  : why `gpg -v --use-embedded-filename bbb.gpg` extract the file ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Because that's how `gpg` was written. If you do not give it any action, it selects the most apropriate one. Given an encrypted file, it decrypts it. (Given a signature, it verifies it. And so on.)

Comment: Thanks for professional answers. p.s. Are you saying that I should never trust this command `$ gpg -v --use-embedded-filename test.gpg` ( just want to extract to the original filename) Im asking this due to the linux sample....Also , didn't understand why I can't use `--decrypt` with `--use-embedded-filename`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes. If you want just the filename, either use `--list-packets` (the best choice), or see my earlier example with `-d`.

Comment: is there any reason for `gpg --use-embedded-filename --decrypt "bbb.gpg"` to dump the data on the screen ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Again, that's how `gpg` was written. The "default action" dumps to a file – but `--decrypt` only writes where it's told to write. You can redirect the output with `--output [filename]` or with `> [filename]`. If you want to discard it, tell gpg to write to the "`nul`" file (or "`/dev/null`" on Linux), as in my example.

Comment: ok man , you provided so much info in a short time... im reading and testing....

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm going to delete my wrong answer.

Comment: @grawity Can you _please_ have a look at a problem i've encountered with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041645/must-gnupg-to-have-installed-keys-for-a-current-username-profile

Comment: Today I run `gpg --use-embedded-filename --decrypt "bbb.gpg"` and no data was output on the screen. Using `--use-embedded-filename` with `--decrypt` seems to correctly output to the embedded filename with no output on stdout (`gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19`).

Answer (score 1):

```
# just placing this here for portable gpg'd tar globs, as a bash function ')

function tgp() {
# en/decrypt fileglobs as tars with gnupg
rcpt='MYUSER'
    case "${1}" in
            e) shift; tar c $* |gpg -er ${rcpt} -o $(date +%s).tgp
            d) shift; gpg -dq ${1} |tar t && gpg -dq ${1} |tar x
            t) shift; gpg -dq ${1} |tar t
            *) echo "Usage: tpg [e|d|t] [glob|file]"
    esac
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).